# to notify JAVA program a new file is uploaded in google drive folder?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

How do you set up an event such that any new file uploaded to a specified Google Drive folder is instantly notified to Java program?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the Google Drive API but this should get you started...

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2

I'd like to see what you come up with when you're done! Good luck!

I dug a little further out of curiosity - 
https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java

Comment: I have my application which stores whatever file is uploaded in google drive but i am unable to notify my java program in backhand that a file is uploaded in the drive